# References to appendix fail after first page

Tags: pdftex, appendices

I have 4 appendixes, and I reference once each one. I have found that pdflatex only finds the references to the first appendix page. I have tried to replicate it in a blank project but I cannot reproduce it.

A part of the error log that might be interesting:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has
been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again>
\relax
l.18
[2
]
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `Appendix' on input line 23.
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `Appendix' on input line 23.
) [3]
\openout2 = `objectives.aux'.
(./objectives.tex) [4
]
\openout2 = `methodology.aux'.
(./methodology.tex) [5
]
\openout2 = `christ.aux'.
(./christ.tex
LaTeX Warning: Reference `app:crosses' on page 6 undefined on input line 8.
[6
]) [7]
\openout2 = `mantegna.aux'.
(./mantegna.tex <mantegna.jpg, id=151, 171.039pt x 144.54pt>
File: mantegna.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use mantegna.jpg> [8
<./mantegna.jpg>] [9] [10]) [11]
\openout2 = `greco.aux'.
(./greco.tex
<elgreco.jpg, id=170, 301.125pt x 481.8pt>
File: elgreco.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use elgreco.jpg> [12
<./elgreco.jpg>] [13] [14]) [15]
\openout2 = `velazquez.aux'.
(./velazquez.tex
<velazquez.jpg, id=190, 476.982pt x 711.27667pt>
File: velazquez.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use velazquez.jpg> [16
<./velazquez.jpg>] (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-30.def
File: uni-30.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode data U+1E00..U+1EFF
) [17]
[18]) [19]
\openout2 = `dali.aux'.
(./dali.tex <dali.jpg, id=209, 853.1875pt x 1535.7375pt>
File: dali.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use dali.jpg> [20
<./dali.jpg>]
LaTeX Warning: Reference `app:sanjuan' on page 21 undefined on input line 33.
```

This is my main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article} % Artículo porque a la hora de poner los títulos los enumera con 1., 2.,... sin embargo el report te los enumera así: 0.1., 0.2.,...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Esto hace que latex interprete la codificación del documento como utf-8 sin dar errores en las tildes
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Para poner el idioma en castellano(fecha,Índice...)
\usepackage{graphicx} %Para las imagenes
\usepackage{caption} %Para los textos de las imágenes
\usepackage{subcaption} % Para los textos de las imagenes tengan varios apartados
%Estas dos líneas (esta y la de abajo)ponen interlineado 1,5 excepto en notas a pie de página e igual algo más (que no sé)
\usepackage{setspace} % Paquete para interlineado.
\onehalfspacing % Interlineado a 1'5
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{uarial}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=4cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=3cm]{geometry} % Para los márgenes

\usepackage{color} % Para poder poner las letras en color si es necesario
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % Para poder poner los Anexos
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos} %Para cambiar de nombre los appendices por anexos
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos} %Para cambiar de nombre los appendices por anexos
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos} %Para cambiar de nombre los appendices por anexos

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linktoc=page]{hyperref} % Para poner links
\usepackage{float}
% Solución para colisiones entre hyperref y appendix
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}
\makeatother
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document} % Siempre hay que ponerlo
\title{Anatomía de superficie: su representación pictórica en el Ecce Homo}
\author{Nerea González Cordero}
\date{\today}
\maketitle % Para crear la portada
\thispagestyle{empty} % Para que no ponga número en la página
\newpage % Para salto de página

\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents % Para el Índice
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % La numeración de las páginas, también se puede con números romanos {roman}

\include{abstract}
\include{intro}
%\include{propor}
\include{objectives}
\include{methodology}
\newpage
\include{christ}
\include{mantegna}
\include{greco}
\include{velazquez}
%\include{gauguin}
\include{dali}
\include{results-and-discussion}
\include{conclu}
%\include{bibliography}
\newpage
\nocite{*} % Show all Bib-entries
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\newpage
\appendix
\begin{appendices}
\let\clearpage\relax
\include{anexos}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

And this is my appendix file, called anexos.tex:

```
\section{Hombre de Vitruvio} \label{app:vitruvio}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{vitruvio2.jpg}
    \caption{Hombre de Vitruvio, el dibujo más conocido de Leonardo Da Vinci} % URL:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Da_Vinci_Vitruve_Luc_Viatour.jpg/300px-Da_Vinci_Vitruve_Luc_Viatour.jpg
\end{figure}

\section{Andrés Vesalio} \label{•}label{app:vesalio}

Andrés Vesalio fue un pionero en el ámbito de la anatomía. En su tratado ``De humani corporis fabrica" se pueden apreciar diversas representaciones de la anatomía del cuerpo humano en movimiento. A continuación están detallados algunos de estos dibujos:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.28\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[height=6cm]{musculos.jpg}
             \caption{Músculos}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.28\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[height=6cm]{nervios.jpg}
             \caption{Nervios}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.28\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=6cm]{esqueleto.jpg}
            \caption{Esqueleto}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.37\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{cabeza.jpg}
             \caption{Cabeza y cerebro}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
             \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{interior.jpg}
             \caption{Órganos internos}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
% http://www.biografiasyvidas.com/biografia/v/vesalio.htm
% http://archive.nlm.nih.gov/proj/ttp/flash/vesalius/vesalius.html
% http://quod.lib.umich.edu/w/wantz/vesd1.htm
% Andrés Vesalio, su vida y su obra Escrito por José Barón Fernández

\section{Tipos de Cruces}
\label{app:cross}

Tradicionalmente existe cuatro tipos de cruces según su morfología específica básica. Estos cuatro modelos son:
%\begin{itemize}
%\item[La cruz Latina, cruz immissa o cruz ordinaria]
%\item[La cruz Griega o cruz immissa quadrata]
%\item[La cruz de San Andrés o cruz decussata]
%\item[La cruz Tau, cruz commissa o en forma de T]
%\end{itemize}

\begin{description}
\item[] La cruz Latina, cruz \textit{Immissa} o cruz ordinaria
\item[] La cruz Griega o cruz \textit{Immissa quadrata}
\item[] La cruz de San Andrés o cruz \textit{Decussata}
\item[] La cruz Tau, cruz \textit{Commissa} o en forma de T
\end{description}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{cruces.jpg}
    \caption{Distintos tipos de cruces} % URL:http://www.crosses.org/history.htm
\end{figure}

\section{Cristo de San Juan de la Cruz} \label{app:sanjuan}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{sanju.jpg}
    \caption{Cristo original de San Juan de la Cruz, que inspiró a Dalí en su obra.} % URL:http://archipielagoduda.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/el-unico-dibujo-conservado-de-san-juan.html
\end{figure}
```

You can find all the current tree project at https://github.com/jouyt/tfg/tree/c99e1ed72e95a2ac32dcf0e624cca05df6d063ed

Comment: You should try to prepare a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) using the *Hacking Down* approach.

Comment: I tried but it works as expected: http://pastebin.com/QBkNYW9m I will try that method thought...

Comment: I have done the hackdown approach, this is the minimal working example, but maximized, it doesn't recognize any \autoref{}:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9710020

Comment: By the way, if `\label{app:cross}` then `\ref{app:crosses}` will fail. The manual for `appendix` says `appendices` is an alternative to `\appendix`...?

Comment: Yeah, the cross VS crosses was a C&P problem, I did many tests on it. The appendices this is defined as "\appto{\appendices}{\def\Hy@chapapp{Appendix}}" in the main file.

Answer (score 1):

Asking in `#latex`, |Zz| told me that I had to use `\input` instead of `\include`. No idea on the exact reason, but substituting the `\include` by `\input` on the `anexos.tex` include fixes.

```
\input{anexos}
```